# Can System.Data.DataRow used for SQL injection?

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql-injection, datarow

I am aware that for SqlCommand I have to use SqlParameter when passing parameters to the query, to avoid SQL injection. But what about the DataRow? For example:

```
row.UserComment = tbUserComment.Text;
```

Here "row" is a System.Data.DataRow that will be saved to the DB with an SqlDataAdapter. And "tbUserComment.Text" is an ASP.NET TextBox that is filled by the user.
Can this be used for SQL injection? If yes, then what can I do to prevent it?

Comment: That question is about something else. That is about the Select command that is run only in memory and not on the DB, and my question is about the actual data that is sent to the DB.

Comment: If you save the contents of a `DataTable` using a data adapter then you are using parameters, so obviously there is no opportunity for SQL injection. SQL injection only occurs when you build SQL code with literal values in it.

Comment: @D.Stanley That duplicate is the wrong one. That refers to using `DataTable.Select`, which is unrelated to (syntax-wise and the mechanism used) to passing a `DataRow` to a `DataAdapter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See in this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

> The InsertCommand, DeleteCommand, and UpdateCommand are generic templates that are automatically filled with individual values from every modified row through the parameters mechanism.

So this will automatically parameterize the `DataRow` meaning there should be no possibility of SQL injection if this pattern is adhered to.